# What commands do I run to change IP NAT settings for a Cisco 2800 series router

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

I am using cisco 2821 router. Initially other person has configured that router. But I just want to change one thing in that router. I need to change this below line.

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.*.*.1 80 117.218.*.* 80 extendable
```

I need to change this line to

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.*.*.2 80 117.218.*.* 80 extendable
```

Just changing the ip address. I know some commands like,

```
RouterR1# show running-config
RouterR1# config t
```

But I don't know how exactly change this particular line in that Router. How can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the "no" form of the command to remove the first statement, then add the second one.  Like this:

```
config t
no ip nat inside source static tcp 172.*.*.1 80 117.218.*.* 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.*.*.2 80 117.218.*.* 80 extendable
```